# How can I delete specific nodes from an XElement?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have created a XElement with node which has XML as below.

I want to remove all the "*Rule*" nodes if they contain "*conditions*" node.

I create a *for* loop as below, but it does not delete my nodes:

```
foreach (XElement xx in xRelation.Elements())
{
  if (xx.Element("Conditions") != null)
  {
    xx.Remove();
  }
}
```

**Sample:**

```
<Rules effectNode="2" attribute="ability" iteration="1">
    <Rule cause="Cause1" effect="I">
      <Conditions>
        <Condition node="1" type="Internal" />
      </Conditions>
    </Rule>
    <Rule cause="cause2" effect="I">
      <Conditions>
        <Condition node="1" type="External" />
      </Conditions>
    </Rule>
</Rules>
```

How can I remove all the "*Rule*" nodes if they contain "*conditions*" node?

Comment: you can't iterate rule elements with foreach while deleting the items. rather you can collection them in a list and the iterate using for loop and delete them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
var nodes = xRelation.Elements().Where(x => x.Element("Conditions") != null).ToList();

foreach(var node in nodes)
    node.Remove();
```

Basic idea: you can't delete elements of collection you're currently iterating.
So first you have to create list of nodes to delete and then delete these nodes.

Comment: The importance of the call to 'ToList()' here to materialise the collection of elements shouldn't be underestimate. Scratched my head for a good few minutes before I landed here and noticed the .ToList() call before the foreach utilisation! (Thank you)

Answer (score 15):

You can use [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
xRelation.Elements()
     .Where(el => el.Elements("Conditions") == null)
     .Remove();
```

Or create a copy of the nodes to delete, and delete them after (in case the first method doesn't work):

```
List nodesToDelete = xRelation
    .Elements()
    .Where(el => el.Elements("Conditions") == null)
    .ToList();

foreach (XElement el in nodesToDeletes)
{
    // Removes from its parent, but not nodesToDelete
    // itself, so we can use foreach here
    el.Remove();
}
```

Comment: I don't think your solution at the top can work. el.Elements("Conditions") == null) will always evaluate to not null.

Comment: @CiaranGallagher well, the answer is 7 years old, but it was upvoted 12 times, so I assume it's been a working solution to OP's issues at the time :)

Answer (score 3):

```
  passiveLead.DataXml.Descendants("Conditions").Remove();
```

This will remove all [descendant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants?view=net-7.0) elements that match the name 'Conditions' for the XML document.

Comment: Can you please add some additional explanation or references for the OP and future readers?

Answer (score 2):

I've made a small example for you:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(GetXml());
var rulesNode = document.Element("Rules");
if (rulesNode != null)
{
    rulesNode.Elements("Rule").Where(r => r.Element("Conditions") != null).Remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var el = xRelation.XPathSelectElement("/Rules/Rule/Conditions");
while (el != null)
{
      el.Remove();
      el = xRelation.XPathSelectElement("/Rules/Rule/Conditions");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just an idea:

Reverse the [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) "condition" and you will get a List without "Rule" nodes.

Comment: Hi! Small answers must go in comments section. Please wait till you have enough reputation to comment. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer