# How do I remove an XML element based on the value of its attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm having difficulties wrapping my head around how to do this, and since it's my first time doing anything with xml, I figured I should ask more experienced people to save some time.

I know how to remove elements. I've loaded the xml into an XDocument. I know how to read elements, and obtain the value of an attribute of an element. I just don't know how to remove multiple elements of the same type based on the value of their attributes. This is a sample of the XML I want to use. I want to remove all effect elements with `type="SetName"`

```
<tech name="Name" type="Normal">
    <displaynameid>11166</displaynameid>
    <effects>
        <effect type="TextOutput"></effect>
        <effect type="Data"></effect>
        <effect type="Data"></effect>
        <effect type="SetName"></effect>
        <effect type="SetName"></effect>
        <effect type="Data"></effect>
        <effect type="SetName"></effect>
        <effect type="SetName"></effect>
        <effect type="SetName"></effect>
    </effects>
</tech>
```

Comment: Welcome DeuSJS!  Could you please provide some examples of what the data looks like, and what you've tried thus far?  We can better provide help then :)

Comment: okay, just edited it.

Comment: see the answer on this stackoverflow question. It is exactly the same question but obviously different xml data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169101/how-to-delete-specific-nodes-from-an-xelement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete specific nodes from an XElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169101/how-to-delete-specific-nodes-from-an-xelement)

Comment: basically you can't delete when you are looping through xml elements. So keep adding elements of interest in a list and then after the loop delete them

Comment: every way I've tried to filter out the elements has ended in either them not getting filtered out, or an exception being thrown, so I need exact code, so that I can learn for next time.

Comment: ah, I figured it out, I forgot to go down a layer

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question because your question is too abstract. But since it will be a long comment therefore I am writing it as an answer.

Let's go step by step about your problem.

If you don't know how to read xml in c# then you can read about `XElement` or `XmlReader`

If you don't know how to read xml elements then google something like "traversing xml c#"

if you don't know how to read element attributes then `XElement` has `Attributes` property which returns a collection of `XAttribute` which has property `Value`

if you don't know how to delete child element then see the following link [How to delete specific nodes from an XElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28169101/how-to-delete-specific-nodes-from-an-xelement)

Comment: yeah, you're right, I'll edit my original post to make it more clear