# How to deserialize XML to get the data from tags?

Tags: c#, xml

I have below XML stored in a string RequestPassengerXML. How can I deserialize it so that I can get the tags information which I can assign it to my class members.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Passenger xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Name>John Vaz</Name>
<Email>john@gmail.com</Email>
<cardNumber>CB2390VT</cardNumber>
</Passenger>
```

I have created a class with below details

```
 public class PassengerDetails
{
    public PassengerDetails();

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string CardNumber{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read and parse an XML file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c)

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640395/10024425

Answer (score 0):

```
public static XElement ToXElement<T>(this object obj)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    { 
        using (TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, obj);
            return XElement.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()));
        }
    }
}

public static T FromXElement<T>(this XElement xElement)
{
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(xElement.CreateReader());
}
```

Usage:

```
XElement element = PassengerDetails.ToXElement<PassengerDetails>();
var newMyClass = element.FromXElement<PassengerDetails>();
```