# getting "null" value for xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

in this xml

```
<Roots>
   <Root Name="cab">element_list</Root>
</Roots>
```

I want to get the value of attribute `Name` which is `cab` and `element_list`

I have this code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<Root Name=\"cab\">element_list</Root>");
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
var values = doc.Descendants("Roots").Select(x => new { Name = (string)x.Attribute("Name"), List = (string)x }).ToList();
```

What I get when I run the debugger is

```
values>  Name = "null",  List = "element_list"
```

I am not understanding why I am getting a `null` value when I should be getting `cab` for the attribute `Name`

Comment: Your `"<Root Name=\"cab\">element_list</Root>"` does not have `.Descendants("Roots")`.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640395/10024425

Comment: @GSerg so how do I change it?

Comment: Introduce a `<Roots>` so that it could be found by `.Descendants("Roots")`? Change `.Descendants("Roots")` to something else so that it would find what there actually is?

Comment: The XML string you're passing to `doc.LoadXml()` is not the same as the XML document at the beginning of the question.  That's significant.

Comment: *In this XML* contains the `<Roots>` element, while you try to load XML with the XML string without `<Roots>` element, so which is the **real** XML data should be?

Answer (score 0):

`XDocument` is *much* easier to work with compared to `XmlDocument`. Perhaps consider switching to it?

```
    public static void ParseXml()
    {
        string str = "<Roots><Root Name=\"cab\">element_list</Root></Roots>";

        using TextReader textReader = new StringReader(str);
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(textReader);

        var val = doc.Element("Roots").Element("Root").Attribute("Name").Value;

    }
```