# C# create XML file from Datatable

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datatable, linq-to-xml

I am new to XML and want to create XML document from datatable

I have a DataTable with following data:

```
Number    DeptNo    DeptName    State    Date        Year    DeptCode        ELP
123A      1001      DESC JR     PA       12/12/2021  2021    74-123           Y
123A      1002      PHIL JR     NY       09/12/2021  2021    74-124           Y
123A      1003      GILB JR     CA       08/12/2021  2021    74-125           N
123A      1004      THEO JR     AZ       07/12/2021  2021    74-126           N
123A      1005      HARR JR     NV       06/12/2021  2021    74-127           Y
123A      1001      DESC JR     FED      06/12/2021  2021    74-123           N
123A      1002      PHIL JR     FED      09/12/2021  2021    74-124           N
```

I need to create an XML file from above DataTable data as below:

```xml
<Root>
    <Type>MyType</Type>
    <FileDate>12/15/2022</FileDate>
    <Version>2.0</Version>
    <Department>
          <Number>123A</Number>
          <Id>0000</Id>
          <Trust>
               <DeptNo>1001</DeptNo>
               <DeptName>DESC JR</DeptName>
               <DeptCode>74-123</DeptCode>
               <DepartmentData>
                     <State>PA</State>
                     <Date>12/12/2021</Date>
                     <Year>2021</Year>
                     <ELP>Y</ELP>
               </DepartmentData>
               <DepartmentData>
                     <State>FED</State>
                     <Date>12/12/2021</Date>
                     <Year>2021</Year>
                     <ELP>N</ELP>
               </DepartmentData>
          </Trust>              
          <Trust>
               <DeptNo>1002</DeptNo>
               <DeptName>PHIL JR</DeptName>
               <DeptCode>74-124</DeptCode>
               <DepartmentData>
                     <State>NY</State>
                     <Date>09/12/2021</Date>
                     <Year>2021</Year>
                     <ELP>Y</ELP>
               </DepartmentData>
               <DepartmentData>
                     <State>FED</State>
                     <Date>09/12/2021</Date>
                     <Year>2021</Year>
                     <ELP>N</ELP>
               </DepartmentData>
          </Trust>
          <Trust>
               <DeptNo>1003</DeptNo>
               <DeptName>GILB JR</DeptName>
               <DeptCode>74-125</DeptCode>
               <DepartmentData>
                     <State>CA</State>
                     <Date>08/12/2021</Date>
                     <Year>2021</Year>
                     <ELP>N</ELP>
               </DepartmentData>
          </Trust>
          <!-- Other Trust nodes skipped -->
    </Department>
</Root>
```

I tried the following but it is not giving me the expected result:

How can I iterate through datatable rows to create XML document?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73638292/create-delete-element-on-xmlnode-c-sharp/73640395#73640395

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you are only creating one `<Trust>` element.  You required XML has multiple repeating `<Trust>` elements, so you need to move creation of these elements inside the `dt.AsEnumerable()` lambda.

You also have a bug with the `<Id>` element: you are creating an element named `<ID>` not `<Id>`.  XML is case sensitive, so elements must always be created with the correct casing.

Finally, a suggestion: you are hardcoding the department `Number` to be `"123A"`, however you can easily group your DataTable rows by the value of the `Number` column, then write the group key instead of the hardcoded value.

Putting it all together, your code should look like:

```
// Group the rows by Department (all 123A in your question).
var departments = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Number")); 

// Generate the root element
var root = new XElement("Root",
    new XElement("Type", "MyType"),
    new XElement("FileDate", "12/15/2022"),
    new XElement("Version", "2.0"),
    departments.Select(
        d =>
        new XElement("Department",
            new XElement("Number", d.Key),
            new XElement("Id", "0000"),  // Fixed, was ID
            d.Select(
                r => 
                new XElement("Trust",
                    new XElement("DeptNo", r.Field<string>("DeptNo")),  
                    new XElement("DeptName", r.Field<string>("DeptName")),   
                    new XElement("DeptCode", r.Field<string>("DeptCode")),
                    new XElement("DepartmentData", 
                        new XElement("State", r.Field<string>("State")),
                        new XElement("Date", r.Field<string>("Date")),
                        new XElement("Year", r.Field<string>("Year")),
                        new XElement("ELP", r.Field<string>("ELP"))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

There should be no need to create the `XDeclaration` node, it should be written for you automatically when you serialize your `XElement` to your final output stream.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DV8qtk).

---

> But how do I group by 'DeptNo'? I have updated the DataTable and expected XML. Sorry I didn't mention this earliar in the question.

You can add an extra [`GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) to additionally group the Department rows by DeptNo, like so:

```
// Group the rows by Department (all 123A in your question).
var departments = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Number")); 

// Generate the root element
var root = new XElement("Root",
    new XElement("Type", "MyType"),
    new XElement("FileDate", "12/15/2022"),
    new XElement("Version", "2.0"),
    departments.Select(
        d =>
        new XElement("Department",
            new XElement("Number", d.Key),
            new XElement("Id", "0000"),  // Fixed, was ID
            // Group Departments by DeptNo. Also collect DeptName and DeptCode in the Key to use later (we assume they are consistent for each DeptNo).
            d.GroupBy(r => (DeptNo : r.Field<string>("DeptNo"), DeptName : r.Field<string>("DeptName"), DeptCode : r.Field<string>("DeptCode"))).Select(
                deptNo => 
                new XElement("Trust",
                    new XElement("DeptNo", deptNo.Key.DeptNo),  
                    new XElement("DeptName", deptNo.Key.DeptName),   
                    new XElement("DeptCode", deptNo.Key.DeptCode),
                    deptNo.Select(data =>
                        new XElement("DepartmentData", 
                            new XElement("State", data.Field<string>("State")),
                            new XElement("Date", data.Field<string>("Date")),
                            new XElement("Year", data.Field<string>("Year")),
                            new XElement("ELP", data.Field<string>("ELP"))
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C3xRU0).

Comment: This works. The DataTable will contain only rows with Number to be "123A".
But how do I group by 'DeptNo'? I have updated the DataTable and expected XML. 
Sorry I didn't mention this earliar in the question.

Comment: I have been trying to add this extra group by, but was getting duplicate results. You saved my day!!