# XML Array without container to Object in VB

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-deserialization

I have some results sent by a third party that I must load in my system, this is the XML format that I receive and I must first deserialize it to a class and then store it in a database.

XML format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RESULTADO>
  <FORMULA>
    <EXAMEN>Hematíes</EXAMEN>
    <RESULTADO>4.76</RESULTADO>
    <RANGO_REFERENCIAL>4.8 - 7.1</RANGO_REFERENCIAL>
    <METODO>Colorimetria</METODO>
    <EXAMEN>Hemoglobina</EXAMEN>
    <RESULTADO>13.30</RESULTADO>
    <RANGO_REFERENCIAL> 12.0 -20.0</RANGO_REFERENCIAL>
    <METODO>Cinetico</METODO>
    <EXAMEN>Hematocrito</EXAMEN>
    <RESULTADO>42.00</RESULTADO>
    <RANGO_REFERENCIAL>44 - 60</RANGO_REFERENCIAL>
    <METODO>Cálculo de Histograma</METODO>
    <EXAMEN>VCM</EXAMEN>
    <RESULTADO>88.2</RESULTADO>
    <RANGO_REFERENCIAL>80.0 - 100.0</RANGO_REFERENCIAL>
    <METODO></METODO>
 </FORMULA>
<GLUCOSA>
    <EXAMEN>GLUCOSA</EXAMEN>
    <RESULTADO>87</RESULTADO>
    <RANGO_REFERENCIAL>70 - 110</RANGO_REFERENCIAL>
    <METODO>Enzimatico</METODO>
</GLUCOSA>
<COLESTEROL>
    <EXAMEN>COLESTEROL</EXAMEN>
    <RESULTADO>259</RESULTADO>
    <RANGO_REFERENCIAL>Mayor a  240</RANGO_REFERENCIAL>
    <METODO>Enzimatico</METODO>
    <EXAMEN>Observaciones:</EXAMEN>
    <RESULTADO>Suero lipémico 2 +.</RESULTADO>
    <RANGO_REFERENCIAL></RANGO_REFERENCIAL>
    <METODO></METODO>
</COLESTEROL>
</RESULTADO>
```

And these are my classes:

```
Public Class RESULTADO
    <XmlElement("FORMULA")>
    Public Property Numeracion As PRUEBA_LABORATORIO
    <XmlElement("GLUCOSA")>
    Public Property Glucosa As PRUEBA_LABORATORIO
    <XmlElement("COLESTEROL")>
End Class

Public Class PRUEBA_LABORATORIO
    Public Property FILA As ITEM_EXAMEN
End Class

Public Class ITEM_EXAMEN
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="EXAMEN", Order:=1)>
    Public Property EXAMEN As String
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="RESULTADO", Order:=2)>
    Public Property RESULTADO As String
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="RANGO_REFERENCIAL", Order:=3)>
    Public Property RANGO_REFERENCIAL As String
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="METODO", Order:=4)>
    Public Property METODO As String
End Class
```

As you can see, each group can have one or more "elements" without a main container (EXAMEN + RESULTADO + RANGO_REFERENCIAL + METODO should count as an element of the array) and that's my problem, I can't create the arrays

Comment: Not sure I follow the question, I don't see anything thing in that XML is looking like an array?  Perhaps something has been lost in your explanation because the XML isn't valid and missing tags?

Comment: _I have some results sent by a third party that I must load in my system_: Ask the third party to correct their XML. The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640395/10024425

Comment: You can use a collection such as generic.List( of  RESULTADO)

Answer (score 0):

As they are company tasks "for yesterday" I had to continue with the trial and error until I found how to read everything:

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Public Class RESULTADO
    <XmlElement("NUMERACION__FORMULA_Y_PLAQUETAS")>
    Public Property Numeracion As PRUEBA_LABORATORIO
    <XmlElement("GLUCOSA")>
    Public Property Glucosa As PRUEBA_LABORATORIO
    <XmlElement("COLESTEROL")>
    Public Property Colesterol As PRUEBA_LABORATORIO
    <XmlElement("HDL_COLESTEROL")>
    Public Property Colesterol_HDL As PRUEBA_LABORATORIO
    <XmlElement("TRIGLICERIDOS")>
    Public Property Trigliceridos As PRUEBA_LABORATORIO
    <XmlElement("SEROLOGICAS_CUALITATIVAS")>
    Public Property Serologicas As PRUEBA_LABORATORIO
    <XmlElement("ANTIGENO_PROSTATICO_ESPECIFICO_PSA")>
    Public Property AntigenoPSA As PRUEBA_LABORATORIO
    <XmlElement("EXAMEN_COMPLETO_DE_ORINA")>
    Public Property Orina As PRUEBA_LABORATORIO
    <XmlElement("THEVENON")>
    Public Property Thevenon As PRUEBA_LABORATORIO
    <XmlElement("PERFIL_LIPIDICO_COMPRENDE_COLESTEROLHD")>
    Public Property PerfilLipidico As PRUEBA_LABORATORIO
End Class

Public Class PRUEBA_LABORATORIO
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="EXAMEN")>
    Public Property EXAMEN As String()
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="RESULTADO")>
    Public Property RESULTADO As String()
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="RANGO_REFERENCIAL")>
    Public Property RANGO_REFERENCIAL As String()
    <XmlElement(ElementName:="METODO")>
    Public Property METODO As String()
End Class
```

And when reading the file:

```
Dim reader As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(RESULTADO))
Dim file As New IO.StreamReader("C:\dev\2023007720.xml")
Dim overview As RESULTADO = CType(reader.Deserialize(file), RESULTADO)
```