Can't write/read my XML files - Banking app
I'm using Visual Studio and trying to put customer/withdrawal/deposit data into an XML file, and then read that file to display the information in the UI. The file doesn't get written or take my data. It seems like my code won't even create the file in the first place.
Write and read functions:
public static List<Customer> ReadXML(string xmlfilepath)
{
    try
    {
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Customer>));

        TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlfilepath);

// ERROR FOUND IN COMMENT BY ALEXANDER PETROV - REPLACE StringReader WITH StreamReader.
customers.AddRange((List)serializer.Deserialize(reader));
reader.Close();
        reader = null;
        serializer = null;

        return customers;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

public static bool WriteXML(List<Customer> customers, string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        FileIO.Delete(filePath);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Customer>));

        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);

        serializer.Serialize(writer, customers);
        writer.Close();

        writer = null;
        serializer = null;

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

Trying to display the customer data on form load.
private void frmBanking_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Read XML file and use it to display customer information
    try
    {
        settings = Program.Configuration.GetSection("MySettings").Get<MySettings>();

        this.Text = settings.Text;

        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Black;

        // customers = CustomerManager.Populate();

        customers = CustomerManager.ReadXML(settings.CustomerXMLFilename);
            
        Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblStatus.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}

I'm also trying to write to file and then display after file is written.
private void btnWriteToFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // write customers and transactions to flat file - similar to WriteXMl function
    try
    {
        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        lblStatus.Text = string.Empty;

        if (customers != null)
        {
            bool results = CustomerManager.WriteXML(customers, settings.CustomerXMLFilename);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblStatus.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // updates the information in the existing objects - similar to ReadXML function
    try
    {
        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        lblStatus.Text = string.Empty;

        customers = CustomerManager.ReadXML(settings.CustomerXMLFilename);
        Refresh();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        lblStatus.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}

If the XML had information in it I think this would all work, but I can't tell why the data is not being written to it.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640395/10024425. You'll find additional posts if you click my username and add xml-serialization in the TextBox after my userid. It's best to get serialization (ie: writing) working first,

The error I mainly get is "There is an error in XML document (1, 1)"

Replace StringReader with StreamReader.

I'd even discourage using xml files for storing this data on the whole. Consider a single- file database maybe (LiteDB, SQLite...)

I'd also encourage you to avoid using files for this.

Then: Do not just rethrow in your catch blocks. If you don't handle it or log, let it bubble up. Also: you really need to start disposing your disposables. Consider using using for that.

This looks to be a duplicate of Deserialization error in XML document(1,1): Replace StringReader with StreamReader and it will work fine. StringReader reads value from the string (which is file name in your case)..  Agree?

Incidentally, In WriteXML(), deleting the old file before the new file is written seems like a risky idea.  Instead, write to a temp file and only replace the old file once the new file has been successfully saved.
