Change values from parsed XML with cs class
I have a xml file named Data.xml with the content:
<Data>
    <Books>
        <Book>
            <Title>Moby Dick</Title>    
            <Author>Herman Melville</Author>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Title>Tom Sawyer</Title>   
            <Author>Mark Twain</Author>
        </Book>
    </Books>
</Data>

and I parse these data with a cs class:
public class Data
{
    private Content[] books;      
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("Book", IsNullable = false)]
    public Content[] Books
    {
        get { return this.books; }
        set { this.books = value; }
    }
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public partial class Content
    {
        private string title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return this.title; }
            set { this.title = value; }
        }
        private string author;
        public string Author
        {
            get { return this.author; }
            set { this.author = value; }
        }
    }
}

This works fine. I declare the class and deserialize the data with no trouble:
Data FileContent = new Data();
XmlTextReader Reader = new XmlTextReader("Data.xml");
XmlSerializer Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
FileContent = (Data)Serializador.Deserialize(Reader);
Reader.Close();

Sorry to place so much working code on this post. My goal is now change some values or add new values to FileContent. If I could do it it will be easy to update the xml file with the new values. However I'm having some difficulties doing it.
For instance, imagine I want to change the first title from Herman Melville to Billy Budd. I tried the code:
FileContent.Books.SetValue("Billy Budd", 0);

This doesn't make sense, because I'm not indexing the element I want to Set and, fairly enough, I get a related runtime error when I run this piece of code. However, the code that makes sense in my head:
FileContent.Books[0].SetValue("Billy Budd", "Title");

or:
FileContent.Books[0].Title.SetValue("Billy Budd");

doesn't work.
How can I change the values on FileContent?
And can you also help me to add new data to FileContent? For instance, how can I add a new book: War and Peace from Leo Tolstoy?
Thanks

So you want to change the value in the in-memory structure and then re-serialize it back to a file? So use your setter FileContent.Books[0].Title = "Billy Bud" and then serialize the File content back to an xml file?

Ok. It's easier than I thought. And how do I add the new book?

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640395/10024425

You need to modify the item in memory and then re-serialize it back to an xml file.
So FileContent.Books[0].Title = "Billy Bud" modifies the value, then you need to write the code to write it back to the xml file. Probably using an XMLTextWriter
Adding books could be done by making a new array with a copy of the current books with your additional new one. A possibly better alternative would to be use the List<Content> type for Data.books rather than Content[] which is dynamic. You could then add a new book like FileContent.Books.Add(new Data.Content(){Author = "Leo Tolstoy", Title = "War and Peace"});

Can you assist me more thoroughly on the second part? I'm not used to do this. Sorry.

an array is fixed length once its been created. So to add more you either need to create a new larger array or use another type - like a list. Lists allow you to add items to it. In the case of XML serialization/Deserialization a list is essentially interchangeable with an array. So switching the types allows you to then add books. and then serialize the results.
