I am unable to find the bug. There is an error in XML document (8, 6)
This line in the static class XmlADTAtomReader is throwing an exception:
xml = (XmlAtomList)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);

I am unable to find the bug.
The error says that there is an error is the XML file at (8, 6).
It seems that the error is being generated because of empty tags.
However, public int? AtomNoInTheBranch { get; set; } is already a nullable integer. That didn't work.
I used IsNullable = true, too. That didn't work either.
This is the XML data file 3x2m_modified.atoms.xml:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<pdb>
  <atom>
    <Protein>3X2M</Protein>
    <AtomSerialNo>1</AtomSerialNo>
    <AtomSymbol>N</AtomSymbol>
    <AtomPosition></AtomPosition>
    <AtomNoInTheBranch></AtomNoInTheBranch>
    <ConnectedToAtomNoInTheBranch></ConnectedToAtomNoInTheBranch>
    <AltLocIndicator>A</AltLocIndicator>
    <ResidueName>ALA</ResidueName>
    <ChainName>A</ChainName>
    <ResidueNo>1</ResidueNo>
    <InsertionCode></InsertionCode>
    <X>-3.589</X>
    <Y>-1.325</Y>
    <Z>-13.286</Z>
    <Occupancy>0.34</Occupancy>
    <TemperatureFactor>5.03</TemperatureFactor>
    <SegmentIdentifier></SegmentIdentifier>
    <SegmentIdentifierSymbol></SegmentIdentifierSymbol>
    <ChargeOfTheAtom></ChargeOfTheAtom>
  </atom>  
</pdb>

And here's my code trying to read this XML and deserialize it:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace PdbLib
{
    [XmlRoot("pdb")]
    public class XmlAtomList
    {
        [XmlElement("atom")]
        public List<XmlAtom> Atoms { get; set; }
    }

    public class XmlAtom
    {
        [XmlElement("Protein")]
        public string Protein { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("AtomSerialNo")]
        public int AtomSerialNo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("AtomSymbol")]
        public string AtomSymbol { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("AtomPosition")]
        public string AtomPosition { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("AtomNoInTheBranch")]
        public int? AtomNoInTheBranch { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ConnectedToAtomNoInTheBranch")]
        public int? ConnectedToAtomNoInTheBranch { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("AltLocIndicator")]
        public string AltLocIndicator { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ResidueName")]
        public string ResidueName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ChainName")]
        public string ChainName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ResidueNo")]
        public int ResidueNo { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("InsertionCode")]
        public string InsertionCode { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("X")]
        public double X { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Y")]
        public double Y { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Z")]
        public double Z { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Occupancy")]
        public double Occupancy { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("TemperatureFactor")]
        public double? TemperatureFactor { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("SegmentIdentifier")]
        public string SegmentIdentifier { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("SegmentIdentifierSymbol")]
        public string SegmentIdentifierSymbol { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("ChargeOfTheAtom")]
        public string ChargeOfTheAtom { get; set; }
    }

    public class XmlADTAtomReader
    {
        public static Dictionary<int, XmlAtom> Data { get; private set; }

        static XmlADTAtomReader()
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlAtomList));

            try
            {
                string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(@"Data\\3x2m_modified.atoms.xml");
                XmlAtomList xml;

                using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
                {
                    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader))
                    {
                        xml = (XmlAtomList)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
                    }
                }

                // Manually handle empty elements
                foreach (var atom in xml.Atoms)
                {
                    atom.AtomNoInTheBranch = !atom.AtomNoInTheBranch.HasValue ? null : atom.AtomNoInTheBranch;
                    atom.ConnectedToAtomNoInTheBranch = !atom.ConnectedToAtomNoInTheBranch.HasValue ? null : atom.ConnectedToAtomNoInTheBranch;
                }

                Data = xml.Atoms.ToDictionary(atom => atom.AtomSerialNo, atom => atom);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using PdbLib;
using System.Linq;

namespace PdbLibTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class XmlADTAtomReaderTests
    {
        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            // Setup code here, if needed
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            // Cleanup code here, if needed
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void XmlADTAtomReader_Deserialize_ValidXml_Success()
        {
            var atom = XmlADTAtomReader.Data[0];

            // Assert the values
            Assert.AreEqual("3X2M", atom.Protein);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, atom.AtomSerialNo);
            Assert.AreEqual("N", atom.AtomSymbol);
            Assert.IsNull(atom.AtomPosition);
            Assert.IsNull(atom.AtomNoInTheBranch);
            Assert.IsNull(atom.ConnectedToAtomNoInTheBranch);
            Assert.AreEqual("A", atom.AltLocIndicator);
            Assert.AreEqual("ALA", atom.ResidueName);
            Assert.AreEqual("A", atom.ChainName);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, atom.ResidueNo);
            Assert.AreEqual("", atom.InsertionCode);
            Assert.AreEqual(-3.589, atom.X);
            Assert.AreEqual(-1.325, atom.Y);
            Assert.AreEqual(-13.286, atom.Z);
            Assert.AreEqual(0.34, atom.Occupancy);
            Assert.AreEqual(5.03, atom.TemperatureFactor);
            Assert.IsNull(atom.SegmentIdentifier);
            Assert.IsNull(atom.SegmentIdentifierSymbol);
            Assert.IsNull(atom.ChargeOfTheAtom);
        }
    }
}

This is the exception I get:
Test Name:  XmlADTAtomReader_Deserialize_ValidXml_Success
Test FullName:  PdbLibTests.XmlADTAtomReaderTests.XmlADTAtomReader_Deserialize_ValidXml_Success
Test Source:    C:\git\ProteinAnalysisTools\utXmlADTAtomReader____unit_test\UnitTest1.cs : line 27
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.4733031

Result StackTrace:  
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderXmlAtomList.Read1_NullableOfInt32(Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderXmlAtomList.Read4_XmlAtom(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderXmlAtomList.Read5_XmlAtomList(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderXmlAtomList.Read6_pdb()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
   at PdbLib.XmlADTAtomReader..cctor() in C:\git\ProteinAnalysisTools\PdbLib\XmlDataReader\XmlAdtAtomReader.cs:line 88
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at PdbLib.XmlADTAtomReader.get_Data()
   at PdbLibTests.XmlADTAtomReaderTests.XmlADTAtomReader_Deserialize_ValidXml_Success() in C:\git\ProteinAnalysisTools\utXmlADTAtomReader____unit_test\UnitTest1.cs:line 29
Result Message: 
Test method PdbLibTests.XmlADTAtomReaderTests.XmlADTAtomReader_Deserialize_ValidXml_Success threw exception: 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'PdbLib.XmlADTAtomReader' threw an exception. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (8, 6). ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.


I'd say nullable works only to allow missing XML elements, not empty elements. if you can#t edit the XML files, you could make the potentially empty elements of type string, then check for empty strings before converting them.

@JimOfAllTrades - you're correct, the <AtomNoInTheBranch></AtomNoInTheBranch> element is the problem.  An empty element cannot be deserialized to either int or int? as shown in Deserialize Xml with empty elements.  user366312, you will need to either fix your XML or introduce a surrogate string property as shown in Deserialize Xml with empty elements and also Deserialize Xml with empty elements in C#, which looks to be duplicates.  Agree?

The easiest way to troubleshoot XML deserialization is to get the serialization working first. If the serialization works correctly, then the deserialization will automatically work. The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640395/10024425. If you use Visual Studio, you can use it to automatically generate the classes from XML.
