BinaryReader doesn't read data correctly
I have a task to save some data to a file. I've used BinaryReader/Writer for it, but it doesn't read (or write) date data correctly. When I view the file itself all the numbers that are there can be read, but instead of the date numbers there are some strange characters. I tried to change the file type, and just in case, explicitly cast the data to int, but nothing helped.
Edit: In idea values int day,month,year should be approximately day = 08, month = 12, year = 2024 but it comes out day = 2092, month = 798209 and year = -399638272 also here is what shows in the file.
Here is the code:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/*Develop a “Student” class. Need to demonstrate the use of this class 
 * (first name, last name, date of birth, group, grades, absences, average score), 
 * results must be written to and read from a file*/

namespace DataToFile
{
    class Student
    {
        private string firstname;
        public string Firstname
        {
            get 
            {
                return firstname;
            }
            set
            {
                firstname = value.Replace(",", "");
            }
        }
        private string lastname;
        public string Lastname 
        { 
            get
            {
                return lastname;
            }
            set
            {
                lastname = value.Replace(",", "");
            }
        }
        private DateTime birthDate;
        public DateTime BirthDate 
        { 
            get
            {
                return birthDate;
            }
        }
        private string group;
        public string Group
        {
            get
            {
                return group;
            }
            set
            {
                group = value.Replace(",", ""); ;
            }
        }
        private List<int> Grades;
        private int passes;
        public int Passes
        {
            get
            {
                return passes;
            }
            set
            {
                if (passes < 0) { passes = 0; }
                passes = value;
            }
        }
        private double avgGrade;
        public double AvgGrade 
        { 
            get
            {
                if (Grades == null || Grades.Count == 0) { return 0; }
                return Grades.Average();
            }
        }
        
        public Student(string firstname, string lastname, DateTime birthdate, string group, int passes) 
        { 
            Firstname = firstname; 
            Lastname = lastname;
            this.birthDate = birthdate; 
            Group = group; 
            Passes = passes;
            Grades = new List<int>();
        }
        public Student(string firstname, string lastname, DateTime birthdate, string group) : this(firstname, lastname, birthdate, group, 0) { }
        public Student() : this("-", "-", DateTime.Today, "-", 0) { }

        public string GradesToString() 
        {
            if (Grades == null || Grades.Count == 0) { return "-"; }
            string res = "";
            foreach (int grade in Grades)
            {
                res += grade + " ";
            }
            res = res.TrimEnd(' ');
            return res;
        }
        public void AddGrade(int grade) { Grades.Add(grade); }
        public void AddGrades(IEnumerable<int> grades) 
        { 
            if(grades == null) { return; }
            foreach(int grade in grades) { Grades.Add(grade); }
        }
        public void ClearGrades() { Grades.Clear(); }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Name: {Firstname} {Lastname}\tBirthdate: {birthDate.Day}.{birthDate.Month}.{birthDate.Year}\tGroup: {Group}\n" +
                $"Grades: {GradesToString()}\nPasses: {Passes}\tAverage Grade: {AvgGrade}";
        }

        public void SaveToFile(string file_path)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file_path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                {
                    bw.Write(Firstname);
                    bw.Write(',');

                    bw.Write(Lastname);
                    bw.Write(",");

                    bw.Write((int)birthDate.Day);
                    bw.Write(".");
                    bw.Write((int)birthDate.Month);
                    bw.Write(".");
                    bw.Write((int)birthDate.Year);
                    bw.Write(",");

                    bw.Write(Group);
                    bw.Write(",");

                    bw.Write(GradesToString());
                    bw.Write(",");

                    bw.Write(Passes);
                }
            }
        }
        public void SaveToFile() { SaveToFile(Firstname + Lastname + ".txt"); }


        public void LoadFromFile(string file_path) 
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file_path))
            {
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                {
                    Firstname = br.ReadString();
                    br.ReadChar();

                    Lastname = br.ReadString();
                    br.ReadChar();

                    int day,month,year;
                    day = br.ReadInt32();
                    br.ReadChar();
                    month = br.ReadInt32();
                    br.ReadChar();
                    year = br.ReadInt32();
                    birthDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
                    br.ReadChar();

                    Group = br.ReadString();
                    br.ReadChar();

                    string gradesString = br.ReadString();
                    Grades = (gradesString == "-"
                        ? new List<int>()
                        : gradesString.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToList());
                    br.ReadChar();

                    Passes = br.ReadInt32();
                }
            }
        }
        public void LoadFromFile() { LoadFromFile(Firstname + Lastname + ".txt"); }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student s1 = new Student("John", "Snow", DateTime.Today, "abc123");
            Console.WriteLine(s1);
            s1.AddGrades(new int[]{ 12, 9, 5, 10, 11 });
            Console.WriteLine(s1);
            s1.SaveToFile();

            Student s2 = new Student();
            Console.WriteLine(s2);
            s2.LoadFromFile("JohnSnow.txt");
            Console.WriteLine(s2);


            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}


If you're interested in using XML, search for xml serialization. For JSON, search for json serialization. Here's a post that may be helpful for XML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640395/10024425

bw.Write(',') and bw.Write(".") are different. The former writes a char, the latter writes a string. This should be considered a typo, but let me say more words.
When using BinaryWriter to write a string, it first writes a length prefix and then writes the content of the string, so there is no need to specify the length of the string when reading. So you don't need separators when writing binary format. For example:
//writing
bw.Write(Firstname);
bw.Write(Lastname);
bw.Write((int)birthDate.Day);
bw.Write((int)birthDate.Month);
bw.Write((int)birthDate.Year);
...

//reading
Firstname = br.ReadString();
Lastname = br.ReadString();
int day,month,year;
day = br.ReadInt32();
month = br.ReadInt32();
year = br.ReadInt32();
birthDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
...


Yes, that was the problem, everything works now, thanks

BinaryReader and BinaryWriter use, as the name suggests: binary, i.e. "not text". You probably want TextWriter and TextReader, specifically via File.OpenText and File.CreateText. Alternatively: use BinaryReader / BinaryWriter, but don't expect to be able to read the file as text.
As an additional option: use a serializer instead; many serializers exist, for binary formats (protobuf, etc) and text formats (json, xml, etc), that will be far more reliable than anything you write by hand, unless you are very experienced with formatters and parsers.

TextWriter and TextReader also write and read data in a formatted way? I only knew about BinaryReader / BinaryWriter

The specific thing that went wrong is that several separators (which you don't need if you use a binary format, but that aside) are written as a string with bw.Write(",");, but then the code that reads the data back tries to skip a character with br.ReadChar();.
Writing a string does not just write every character of the string, but also prefixes the string with its length so that ReadString knows where to stop. For the short string of 1 character "," and "." that results in that character prefixed with the length of 1, which is shown as the SOH character (which has the value 1) (the length is encoded in a variable-length format, longer strings are prefixed with more bytes to represent the length). After the first such string is unsuccessfully skipped with ReadChar(), the reader becomes desynchronized from the data format and everything goes bad.

Yes, that was the problem, everything works now, thanks
