How to read and load an XML file with nested tags into a DataTable without DuplicateNameException?
How to read and load an XML file with nested tags into a DataTable without DuplicateNameException?
I need to read and load an XML file with over 600,000 lines to update table in database. The file has two main tags that divide objects:

<listaNcm>: This tag relates multiple <atributo> items listed in <listaAtributos> to a specific <codigoNcm>.

<detalhesAtributos>: This tag contains specific characteristics of each <atributo>. Some of these attributes reference others as related characteristics.
The problem arises in the second part of the file (<detalhesAtributos>), where there is a repeating <orgao> tag. This tag appears both in the main <atributo> and its "child" <condicionados> tag, which contains a list of related <atributos>.


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listaNcm>
...
</listaNcm>
<detalhesAtributos>
        <atributo>
            <codigo>ATT_8838</codigo>
            <nome>Destinação 4814</nome>
            <nomeApresentacao>Destinação</nomeApresentacao>
            <formaPreenchimento>LISTA_ESTATICA</formaPreenchimento>
            <dataInicioVigencia>2023-11-06</dataInicioVigencia>
            <dataFimVigencia></dataFimVigencia>
            <dominio>
                <itemDominio>
                    <codigo>1</codigo>
                    <descricao>Revestimento de parede</descricao>
                </itemDominio>
                <itemDominio>
                    <codigo>2</codigo>
                    <descricao>Papel para vitrais</descricao>
                </itemDominio>
                <itemDominio>
                    <codigo>999</codigo>
                    <descricao>Outros (especifique)</descricao>
                </itemDominio>
            </dominio>
            <objetivos>
                <objetivo>
                    <codigo>7</codigo>
                    <descricao>Produto</descricao>
                </objetivo>
            </objetivos>
> first 
            <orgaos>
                <orgao>RECEITA</orgao>
            </orgaos>
            <atributoCondicionante>true</atributoCondicionante>
            <condicionados>
                <obrigatorio>true</obrigatorio>
                <multivalorado>false</multivalorado>
                <dataInicioVigencia>2023-11-06</dataInicioVigencia>
                <dataFimVigencia></dataFimVigencia>
                <descricaoCondicao> 'ATT_8838' Igual '999'</descricaoCondicao>
                <condicao>
                    <operador>==</operador>
                    <valor>999</valor>
                </condicao>
                <atributo>
                    <codigo>ATT_8682</codigo>
                    <nome>Especifique destinação 5897</nome>
                    <nomeApresentacao>Especifique destinação</nomeApresentacao>
                    <formaPreenchimento>TEXTO</formaPreenchimento>
                    <tamanhoMaximo>70</tamanhoMaximo>
                    <obrigatorio>true</obrigatorio>
                    <multivalorado>false</multivalorado>
                    <dataInicioVigencia>2023-11-06</dataInicioVigencia>
                    <dataFimVigencia></dataFimVigencia>
                    <dominio/>
                    <objetivos>
                        <objetivo>
                            <codigo>7</codigo>
                            <descricao>Produto</descricao>
                        </objetivo>
                    </objetivos>
> here is the error
                    <orgaos>
                        <orgao>RECEITA</orgao>
                    </orgaos>
                    <atributoCondicionante>false</atributoCondicionante>
                    <listaSubatributos/>
                </atributo>
            </condicionados>
            <listaSubatributos/>
        </atributo>
> More like the above
</detalhesAtributos>

When trying to load this structure into a DataSet, I get the following exception:
$exception {"Cannot add a column named 'orgao': a nested table with the same name already belongs to this DataTable."} System.Data.DuplicateNameException.
public string LerArq(string pathXML)
{
    DataSet dsXml = new DataSet();
    string sResult = string.Empty;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pathXML) && File.Exists(pathXML))
    {
        try
        {
            dsXml.ReadXml(pathXML);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    return sResult;
}

How can I resolve this issue and properly load the XML file into a DataSet without conflicts caused by duplicate column names?
Is there another way to handle XML?
I've already tried loading the XML into a DataSet, but I don't have much experience with XML manipulation or handling the file to work around this issue.

I don't have much experience with XML:  XML has been around for a very long time so there are numerous resources available for you to learn about it. You'll find that there are multiple ways to work with XML. It sounds that you've chosen the one least likely to work for you. The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73640395/10024425

Thanks for helping.
I found the XmlNode, XmlNodeList and XmlDocument classes that help me read this document without errors.
